# Change only the width of an image (css only)

Tags: html, image, css, aspect-ratio

I have an image (say 150 x 300), and I want to change *just* the width to 1 pixel but want the image to maintain its original height of 300 pixels (there is actual logic to this end goal, I swear). So my final image would be 1 x 300.

Of course this should be as easy as:

```
img {
    width:1px;
    height:300px;
}
```

But the tricky part is, I don't know the height of the image. This image is dynamic and could have any dimensions. How can I force CSS to ignore the aspect ratio and make the height maintain its initial value? I know this would be quite easy with jQuery, but I'd like to accomplish it with CSS alone. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question is... why would you even want to do that to a 150x300 image?

Comment: I figured that would be asked ;) The reason does not add any additional information that would help answer this question - which is why it was omitted in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure CSS you may use `clip` in conjunction with `position: absolute`

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px 1px auto 0);
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/siyDe

As you can see, you don't need to specify the height of the image (`auto` does the trick). In a real page you would probably need to enclose the image in a container with `position: relative`

Comment: This definitely works. Just out of curiosity, do you know of a way to accomplish the 1x300 without using absolute positioning?

Comment: Unfortunately clip works only for element with position absolute

Answer (score 3):

If the `height` attribute is defined on your image, your can simply achieve it with this CSS:

```
img {
  width: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yvr57/

Comment: I do not know the height of the image, so I would be unable to set the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "resize the image WITHOUT taking into account the aspect ratio", you can set the CSS3's `object-fit` property of the image to `object-fit: fill`.

```
img {
  width: 1px;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

Comment: Hmm didn't have success. Can you provide a fiddle with a working example?

Comment: Seems to be very interesting, but sadly badly supported: http://caniuse.com/object-fit - here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bptZ5/1/ +1 anyways.